# Using $eq and case sensitivity with Artifactory Query Language

Tags: curl, artifactory, artifactory-query-lang

I have an artifact called "myCompany.MyPackage.123.nupkg" however, if I search for that using AQL like below, I don't get any results back. Is it possible to exclude case sensitivity when searching via AQL?

```
items.find({ "name":{"$eq":"mycompany.mypackage.123.nupkg"} })
```

Searching with correct casing does work (like below) but in some cases I want to find without knowing the casing of my package

```
items.find({ "name":{"$eq":"myCompany.MyPackage.123.nupkg"} })
```

Thanks

Comment: Looks like not supported at this movement https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-14971

Comment: Thank you - that's a shame, guess I'll have to wait